# Fill the login form before or after redirection to url automatically

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have ASP.NET Web Application that contains links to our other sites which runs locally.

So user is entering one address and got shortcuts to other addresses.

One of this pages has login form, and everytime user enter this page he has to fill it again and again. Saving login and password in browser is not an option.

I would like to make something that will automatically fill this form, but I am almost sure that I can't change this page.

The solution that I was thinking is that maybe I can open page with login form inside my own page and then use some JS to insert login & password? Is it possible?

This is source code of form that I would like to fill.

```
<div id="loadedLoginPage"><input type="hidden" name="hidChallenge" value="">
<table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><label for="txtUserID" id="TEXT_LOGIN_USER_NAME">User name:</label></td>
        <td class="inputLength"><input type="text" name="txtUserID" id="txtUserID" value="" onchange="hideErrorMessage();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="txtPassWord" id="TEXT_LOGIN_PASSWORD">Password:</label> </td>
        <td><input type="password" name="txtPassWord" id="txtPassWord" value="" onchange="hideErrorMessage();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="txtDomainName" id="TEXT_LOGIN_DOMAIN">Domain:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txtDomainName" id="txtDomainName" value="" onchange="hideErrorMessage();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="chkRememberMe" class="chkRememberMe">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chkRememberMe">
                            <span id="TEXT_LOGIN_REMEMBER_ME">Remember me on this computer:</span>
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <!--<td> <input id="chkRememberMe" name="chkRememberMe" type="checkbox"  /></td>
                    <td><label for="chkRememberMe" id="TEXT_LOGIN_REMEMBER_ME" ></label></td>-->
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="btnLogin" class="buttonLogon" id="TEXT_LOGIN_LOG_ON" value="Log on" onclick="handleLogOnClick()"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div id="errorDivWrap" name="errorDivWrap" align="right" style="display: none;">
    <div id="errorImageDiv" name="errorImageDiv" style="display: none;">
        <img src="/login/images/Error_Stop.png?v=1.7.1.89" width="16" height="16" alt="" id="errorImage" name="errorImage" style="visibility: hidden;">
    </div>
    <div id="errorTextDiv" name="errorTextDiv" style="display: none;">
        <label id="errorTextField" name="errorTextField" style="visibility: hidden;">
    </label></div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: You could open the login page in an iframe or via an ajax request, but you will have to save the password, username in the browser (e.g. sessionStorage).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.